# Cannot trigger build via push to another repository in a YML Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have the following repositories:

- `my-app-repo` - Contains the code for the app
- `pipeline-repo` - A collection of pipelines that build my-app-repo as well as others

I'm trying to build a yml pipeline within `pipeline-repo` that will be triggered on a commit to `my-app-repo`.

According to [the official yml documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md), it sounds possible but I'm not able to get it working.

Here's what I've tried:

**pipeline-repo/my-app-repo-build.yml**

```
resources:         
  repositories:
  - repository: target_repo      
    type: git
    name: my-project/my-app_repo
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master

jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
      - script: echo "Should be triggered from a push to my-app-repo!"
```

The build is not triggering when I push to `my-app-repo`. It only kicks off for commits to the *source* repo (`pipeline-repo`) which I cannot change since that holds the yml definition.

Am I missing something easy?

Comment: Hi, I'm currently looking for such feature, I'm wondering if you found a solution for this issue or there is no way so far?

Comment: @Matrix I am also investigating this type of setup. Do you know if it supported now  (june 2020)?

Comment: @OvidiuBuligan I'm not sure, I haven't seen any news about that.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

I see you've added an issue to the github repository you mentioned. I agree that it seems to be broken.

While you aren't **exactly** trying to provide template functionality to your pipelines, you might use it as a work around until the issue you created is addressed.

I've tested this in my playground and it seems to work.

#### In the app repository

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: Pipeline-Templates      

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

jobs:
- template: azure-pipelines-template.yml@templates
```

#### In the pipelines repository

```
jobs:
- job: Get_Last_10_Commits
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        Write-Host "Show git log (last 10):"
        git log --oneline -10
```

**One "advantage"** of this work around is that you no longer need to specify that the repository to **checkout** is the resource repository and not the **self** (your template-repository) as the **self** repository is the app-repo.

This would allow you to restrict changes to the pipeline core by having it in a separate repo like you want, but would still trigger on the app-repo master.

Not ideal b/c you now have 2x .yml files for each build you need, but that's basically the definition of work around: **not ideal**.

---

It looks like your `include` syntax is wrong. Have you tried to use the **[simple syntax](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md#examples--repo-triggers)**?

All of the examples (and my experience) show that you should use the wildcard syntax when your trigger has an `include` or `exclude` specification.

```
resources:         
  repositories:
  - repository: myPHPApp      
    type: GitHub
    connection: myGitHubConnection
    source: ashokirla/phpApp
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - features/*
        exclude:
        - features/experimental/*
      paths:
        exclude:
        - README.md
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work either. According to (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards) "For paths, you may include * as the final character, but it doesn't do anything differently from specifying the directory name by itself.". In my case above, I'm just listing master plainly as in the example in your link.

Comment: Additionally, it looks as if the `azure-pipelines-yaml` repo's documentation is out of date. It does not match with the official schema reference it seems (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#repository-resource). I'm now not sure if what I'm after is even possible.

Comment: Are you separating the yaml from the source to employ templates?

Comment: Not exactly - The desire was to co-locate a set of application pipelines together for organizational and access related reasons.